# How to avoid code duplication with function overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I have a pair of overloaded functions:

```
void func(const std::string& str, int a, char ch, double d) {
    // piece of code A
    sendMsg(str, a, ch, d);
    // piece of code B
}

void func(int a, char ch, double d) {
    // piece of code A
    sendMsg(a, ch, d);
    // piece of code B
}
```

`piece of code A` and `piece of code B` are exactly the same, the only difference is the parameter of `sendMsg`.

Is there some way to avoid the code duplication?

Comment: What does sendMsg look like?

Comment: @mfnx  It doesn't matter, no? `sendMsg` is a library function, which does some socket job. I can't change it anyway.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Why can't we move A and B to its own functions? Anyone please explain.

Comment: @InQusitive Because A and B shared some data. Making another two functions will make things more complex and make code ugly.

Comment: @Yves thats the problem with asking how to avoid code without showing the code ;) No worries, I guess its a general difficulty with this kind of questions

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah, `piece of code A/B` contains shared data and some locks and other functions...

Comment: @Yves, 'not sure why shared data and locks would be an issue here? As the others have said, it's difficult to answer without simple `foo` example of why you can't throw sections `A` and `B` into functions. Otherwise, nice question.  =)

Comment: IMO question is stripped from important details. This responses to answers `not suitable for my case` is best prove of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

template may be a possibility:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto func(const Ts&... args)
-> decltype(sendMsg(args...), void()) // SFINAE to only allow correct arguments
{
    // piece of code A
    sendMsg(args...);
    // piece of code B
}
```

but moving `// piece of code A` in its own function would probably be my choice.

Answer (score 8):

You would have to do something like

```
void codeA() {
    // ...
}

void codeB() {
    // ...
}

void func(const std::string& str, int a, char ch, double d) {
    codeA();
    sendMsg(str, a, ch, d);
    codeB();
}

void func(int a, char ch, double d) {
    codeA();
    sendMsg(a, ch, d);
    codeB();
}
```

Comment: Well, add two functions are not suitable for my case.

Answer (score 6):

Another idea would be to give a default value to `str`:

```
void func(int a, char ch, double d, const std::string& str = "")
{
    // piece of code A
    if (str.empty()) sendMsg(a, ch, d);
    else sendMsg(str, a, ch, d);
    // piece of code B
}
```

Comment: it can be `const std::string&` also with a default.

Comment: also this will inhibit calling `sendMsg(str,a,ch,d)` when `str == ""` (but not the default one). Thats why I suggest to use `std::optional` instead (though we don't know what `sendMsg` is, it may not matter)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, of course... I'll correct that.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, use a functor:

```
template <typename F> void func2(F&& f) {
    // piece of code A
    f();
    // piece of code B
}
```

Usage:

```
void func(int a, char ch, double d) {
    func2([&](){ sendMsg(a, ch, d); });
}
```

*A bit of explanation:* Currently accepted answer is totally fine when you need to call the exactly same code with different parameters. But when you need to "inject" an arbitrary code (possibly a multiple pieces of arbitrary code) into another function, passing a temporary lambda is your best bet. Conceptually, what receiving function is seeing/getting is some abstract "callable" object (in fact, it can be anything with `operator ()`, not just lambda) which it calls at due time. And since its a templated function, it will be compiled into zero-overhead code "as if" actual code was copy-pasted in there. The usage part is simply shows a c++ syntax to create a callable with arbitrary code in-place (I advise to read language references/tutorials on lambdas to understand the internals better).

Comment: Sure, please don't hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: Oh I got it. Good solution~

Comment: The only issue is that we don't know whether the OP needs to use the inputs for more than just calling `sendMsg` . This is of an issue with the question rather the solution here.